# How to clean up picklist data

Tags: picklist, data, cleanup

My org has been around for quite a while and some admins were more meticulous than others about cleaning up old single- and multi-select picklist values.

Well, I'm one of the more-meticulous sort and I'd like my users to have clean data.

Is there a pre-existing way to go through my org, picklist field by picklist field, and find out which values are in records and no longer in the metadata, and then figure out how to fix them?  I can easily write the Batchable class, but it seems like someone else already has.

Comment: I assume you are talking about records with Picklist values no longer in the metadata?

Comment: @cropredy yes, that.

Comment: I suppose you could make the picklists 'restricted', then use Data Loader to run an update and find out which records are in error to get a sense of the scale of the problem

Comment: @cropredy I don't think you can change a picklist to/from restricted as of Summer '16.  Also, wouldn't that cause massive errors in production?

Comment: Ah yes, a good point.  Full copy sandbox would be the way but if summer 16 restricted this then this idea is a NOP

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to run a report with the filters having a picklist not equal to then your list of values you want to keep. You may be able to just go to the printable view of the values and copy/paste them. Then export the report. Make sure you grab the ID's so you can easily update with the data loader. Use Excel to make any updates you need.

Comment: This does not work for multiselects, which are included in my data

Comment: Also this is so far from automated, that it's very error-prone.  Especially if users change data between when I run the report and when I upload it.